# Databricks create table at delta with fixed varchar(x) data types and timestamp_ntz (no time stamp) columns

Tags: azure, databricks, delta-lake

Can a table be created in Azure Databricks pointed to azure storage account in delta format with fixed `varchar(x)` and `timestamp_ntz` (no time zone) data type ?
I am using a script similar to below and it doesn't like the `varchar(x)` datatype.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE schm.tbl
USING
DELTA
LOCATION
'abfss://cont@storage.dfs.core.windows.net/path/'
(
    col1 VARCHAR(150),
    col2 VARCHAR(6),
    col3 INT,
    col4 VARCHAR(30),
    col5 TIMESTAMP_NTZ
)
TBLPROPERTIES ('delta.feature.timestampNtz' = 'supported');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the reference of Databricks [supported data types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-datatypes).

There is no `varchar(x)` type, use `string` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can create table with `varchar(x)` datatype . please make sure you are using latest DBR version clusters . I have used `13.3 LTS (includes Apache Spark 3.4.1, Scala 2.12)` DBR for below testing . [image]